# При запуске pgAdmin 4 выдает ошибку The application server could not be contacted MACOS!

Tags: postgresql, macos

При запуске вот такая ошибка, стоит MacOs High Sierra

```
The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted:
pgAdmin Runtime Environment
--------------------------------------------------------
Python Path: "/Library/PostgreSQL/15/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python3"
Runtime Config File: "/Users/admin/Library/Preferences/pgadmin/runtime_config.json"
pgAdmin Config File: "/Library/PostgreSQL/15/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/Resources/web/config.py"
Webapp Path: "/Library/PostgreSQL/15/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/Resources/web/pgAdmin4.py"
pgAdmin Command: "/Library/PostgreSQL/15/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python3 -s /Library/PostgreSQL/15/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/Resources/web/pgAdmin4.py"
Environment: 
  - TMPDIR: /var/folders/fx/6l863z8d21j4q15840vn9tfw0000gn/T/
  - __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING: 0x1F5:0x7:0x31
  - HOME: /Users/admin
  - SHELL: /bin/bash
  - _: /usr/bin/open
  - SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT: 0
  - Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render: /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.zLQwGo6Zg2/Render
  - SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.4d4B7C9VSQ/Listeners
  - SHLVL: 1
  - PATH: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
  - LOGNAME: admin
  - XPC_SERVICE_NAME: org.pgadmin.pgadmin4.6172
  - COMMAND_MODE: unix2003
  - MallocNanoZone: 0
  - USER: admin
  - XPC_FLAGS: 0x0
  - PWD: /
  - PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 51313
  - PGADMIN_INT_KEY: 0431b17a-a0dc-4626-a7f0-db25d267af09
  - PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF
--------------------------------------------------------

Total spawn time to start the pgAdmin4 server: 0.011 Sec
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/PostgreSQL/15/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/Resources/web/pgAdmin4.py", line 93, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "/Library/PostgreSQL/15/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/Resources/web/pgadmin/__init__.py", line 542, in create_app

    driver.init_app(app)
  File "/Library/PostgreSQL/15/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/Resources/web/pgadmin/utils/driver/__init__.py", line 27, in init_app
    DriverRegistry.load_modules(app)
  File "/Library/PostgreSQL/15/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/Resources/web/pgadmin/utils/driver/registry.py", line 18, in load_modules
    from . import psycopg2 as module
  File "/Library/PostgreSQL/15/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/Resources/web/pgadmin/utils/driver/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    import psycopg2
  File "/Library/PostgreSQL/15/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/PostgreSQL/15/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-310-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /Library/PostgreSQL/15/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/../../../../../../../../../Contents/Frameworks/libcrypto.3.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Library/PostgreSQL/15/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/../../../../../../../../../Contents/Frameworks/libcrypto.3.dylib
```

Comment: В ошибке "which was built for Mac OS X 10.15". На сайте https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-macos/  "A macOS App Bundle containing the pgAdmin 4 Desktop Runtime and Web application is available for macOS 10.15 and above." Я так понимаю, тебе надо и третий раз сказать - найди совместимую версию. Например, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65870701/pgadmin4-doesnt-open-on-mac

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/